# Scripting engine for OS X application

Tags: objective-c, macos, scripting

I am going to develop an application for OS X and I need some scripting engine for it.
The purpose of the scripts is to receive a text on their input (HTML file in most cases), parse it in some way and return the data to my app. These scripts should be easily editable by the users, therefore they should have some common used syntax like C or pascal.

Can you suggest some lightweight solution for this?

Thanks!

PS. I am new to OS X development, trying to switch from Windows...

Comment: Will the users be developers, general users, or some other group? If the target audience is familiar with scripting that could point to a different answer than if they would likely be writing scripts for the first time.

Comment: David, the scripting feature will be used by the developers only, I think. However, it shouldn't require deep programming knowledge or new syntax learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general AppleScript/Automator actions are easy for the end user to work with since the technology includes a GUI for building scripts without much programming knowledge. For experienced developers used to other languages, they can be a bit *too* friendly/loose and have a somewhat different syntax (more like plain English). The good thing is that they can also call other languages as needed, so a developer familiar with Perl or whatever could incorporate that into an AppleScript or Automator action.

Since you're talking about parsing text, Perl itself would be a good solution - again there's some difference in syntax, but the scripts can be rather compact and the basics of parsing aren't too difficult to learn. I haven't personally incorporated Perl into an OS X app, I've just used it on the command line, so I don't know if there are any pitfalls to that approach.

One additional advantage to AppleScript is that you can make your application itself scriptable so that users could automate the functions of your application into a larger workflow.

I would suggest downloading the free [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) application by Bare Bones Software, or a similar developer's text editor, to see how they incorporate scripting into the application. This may give you additional insight into your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

1. Javascript, try the V8 engine. http://code.google.com/p/v8/  Very popular, likely familiar syntax to many.
2. Lua. http://www.lua.org  Extremely lightweight and simple to connect. If your script editors write scripts for World of Warcraft, for example, they will know Lua.

Answer (score 0):

LUA seems to be a good choice.